How can I avoid relocation records in a Mach-O object?
I'm compiling C code to reimplement some functions in a binary that I'm emulating. Everything was going well until I encountered an issue with certain instructions in the object file generated by the compiler. Specifically, the call instructions lacked immediate values, effectively making them jump to nowhere. After some investigation, I discovered that the problem is due to unresolved relocations, which are normally handled by the loader. Since I'm emulating the code, I don't have the benefit of a loader. While I could manually patch the binary, I would prefer to avoid this workaround. Is there a way to instruct Clang not to produce relocations and simply use the information available at compile time?
Example
Compiling the following code
static int volatile i = 1;

__attribute__((noinline)) int x(void) {
    return i;
}

__attribute__((noinline)) int y(void) {
    return x();
}

with the following command
clang -c -f'freestanding' -f'no-PIC' ./main.c

produces a binary with relocations:
% objdump -r ./main.o                            

main.o: file format mach-o 64-bit x86-64

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [__text]:
OFFSET           TYPE                     VALUE
0000000000000015 X86_64_RELOC_BRANCH      _x
0000000000000006 X86_64_RELOC_SIGNED      _i

I would like to have some compiler flag to prevent addresses to x and i from being relocated and have no relocation table in the final object.

You don't have a binary, you have an unlinked object file. Drop the -c flag.

Depending on your needs you could also compile as a shared object or dylib, which would also immediately resolve internal symbols but still make it possible to have external unresolved symbols.
